# WCF TransactionScope in Client or Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Lets say I need to call multiple services that insert some records with EF in the same transaction which are for inserting `Person` and `Unit`.

I'm uncertain for whether I should create a new operation contract named `AddPersonAndUnit` and use `TransactionScope` in that method and calling it from the client OR don't create any additional method and just use `TransactionScope` in the client (ASP.NET MVC client) and call `AddPerson` and `AddUnit` which are already existing.

For single responsibility and moving all business logic into service layer, I think defining an extra method in service layer and calling it from the client seems a better choice but on the other hand just calling these multiple methods from the client requires less effort.

What do you think with the respect of a good design choice? Do you think dealing with the transactions in client is "bad"? Is it worth it to create a new method for this?

Comment: WCF transactions use MSDTC, which is traditionally hard to configure and support. My advice is don't use it without a reason.

Comment: We need to use MSDTC since some of our services need to call another services and should run in a single transaction

Comment: I'd vote for adding methods to the service - A transaction scope can be managed in service for the two operations but at least that way it doesn't need to extend to the client, just the repository and service layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you're having two projects (`ASP.NET MVC` & `WCF`) and you want to make sure `Person` and `Unit` are being **inserted/updated transactionally**

Taking those two as inputs

---

Let's do quick analysis about option 1 (**Use TransactionScope in client code (proxy class)**)

1. **Efforts needed**

   - Modify Service Contract classes (`OperationContract` and `ServiceBehavior`) to support transaction
   - Decorating existing methods (`OperationBehavior`) to suppor transaction
   - Modify `binding` config
   - Re-config client `binding` configuration
2. **PROS (CLAIM TO BE)**:

   - Requires less efforts => As described in point **1.**, in my opinion, it's difficult to say this method requires less efforts to implement unless everything was is in place
3. **CONS**:

   - Since both application code (`MVC`) and service code (`WCF`) are being **controlled fully by you**, you can make sure that you ALWAYS use the transaction when insert/update `Person` and `Unit`. However, I would prefer to make it as `black-box` service, so that I could expose it to other 3rd client  or give the service to another developer to use **without worrying about data inconsistency** (what if they forgot/intentionally skip the transaction?). Even though you can force the client to ALWAYS use transaction when calling the web services (by using `TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory` option), I think the good practice is only expose minimal service for client to use
   - Single Responsibility is also another concern
   - Duplicate codes (you will need to copy the code over and over every time you want to insert `Person` & `Unit`)

---

Hope it helps,

Sorry for bad English

Comment: +1d but isn't the efforts you listed are also for the second case too (Use TransactionScope in service code )? I totally agree with your points listed in "CONS" though.

Comment: @sotn: no, for the second case, you don't need to use transaction in the `client` code, so you don't need to configure the WCF

Comment: but what about service to service calls? I mean AddPersonAndUnit will call AddPerson and AddUnit services which means services can be client for some other services

Comment: @sotn: yes, it's also possible, and everything will be written in `service` layer (internally), so my point is still valid (*You don't need to configure the WCF to support transaction in client*)